# check if .load has actually loaded content yet, then slide down

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I want to slide down some content that is loaded with jquery .load function

I have this where I load the content and then **Hide** it

```
 function froth(){
   $("#area").hide();
   $("#area").load("test.html #enquiry1");
   $("#area").hide();
}
```

Here I want to make sure that when i click the button it loads the document and then once its loaded then it slides down the content.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#t1').on('click', function(){
    froth();
    $('#area').ready(function(){$("#area").slideDown('slow');})

});
});
```

Any ideas on how to do this.

I've been looking at the API's and it looks like i will probably have to use some ajax function instead... but i wanted to see if there was any other way.

Answer (score 4):

`.load` accepts a callback as parameter http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$("#area").load("test.html #enquiry1", function() {alert('done')});
```

Answer (score 1):

use the callback function of load to make sure the load content is loaded first.. and then do the animation

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#t1').on('click', function(){
    froth();
  });
});

function froth()
{
  $("#area").hide();
  $("#area").load("test.html #enquiry1",function(){
       $(this).slideDown('slow')
  });
}
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#t1').on('click', function(){
     $("#area").hide().load("test.html #enquiry1",function(){
       $(this).slideDown('slow')
     });
  });
});
```